# Rotate image continuously

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to rotate the ring image constantly in anticlockwise direction here is my code

```
public class SpriteSheet extends ApplicationAdapter {
    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        stage=new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        Group group=new Group();

        Image background =new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png")));
        Image button=new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("btn.png")));
        Image ring=new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ring2.png")));

        background.setName("background");
        button.setName("button");
        ring.setName("ring");

        group.addActor(background);
        group.addActor(button);
        group.addActor(ring);

        stage.addActor(group);

        background.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-background.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-background.getHeight()/2);
        button.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-button.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-button.getHeight()/2);

        ring.setPosition(255,105);

        ring.setOrigin(255f,105f);
        ring.rotateBy(2f); // I need continuous rotation here
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: what problems you have? which result are you having now?

Comment: ring.rotateBy(2f); neither rotates nor  give constant rotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the [`Actions`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html) are what you are looking for.
An `Action` can be added to `Actor`s (and subclasses) and they will be performed inside the `act(delta)` method, of the `Actor`.
In your case you could use the `Actions.rotateBy(float rotationAmount, float duration)` and let it repeat forever by using `Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER, rotateAction)`.

So your final code should look like this:

```
ring.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER, Actions.rotateBy(rotation, duration)));
```

Where `rotation` is the rotation amount (i guess in degrees, but i am not sure) and `duration` is the time it should take to rotate by the given amount (given in seconds).

Comment: thanks man it was really helpful but i want the rotation at the center point of the ring like wheel in a car

Comment: For that you need to set the `Actor`s origin to it's center. The origin is relative to the lower, left corner of your `Actor`, so it's center should be P(width/2, height/2). The origin defines the point around which the `Actor` is rotated and scaled, but it does not affect it's position.